# Is there a specific term for the use of adjectives?

Tags: terminology

Is there a ***specific*** term or designation for the act of adding an adjective to something?

"The act of adding an adjective" could generally be called an "edit".  However, the question is whether a term exists specifically for this use of an adjective.

Comment: You might use 'modify' or 'qualify' on occasion, but it takes a bit of thought  to ascertain what's being modified by 'mere' in 'He's a mere youth'. And there are other modifiers.

Comment: Would "the act of adding an adjective" be called **editing**?

Comment: There are no words for adding one of any particular part of speech. This is not anything linguists feel the need for.

Comment: What @JohnLawler said. That said, you might say that adding an adjective *qualifies* its target.